# how to change shibboleth from cookie to query string?

Tags: java, .net, saml, shibboleth

how can it be done to get shibboleth to change the way it manages sessions (a la cookies) to use the query string instead?

i am seeing problems with cross site development because IE refuses the cookie while FF doesn't.

i tried adding p3p headers to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set relayState value in Session tag? You can choose URL or cookie or others. I am not sure if that will fix your needs.

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPSessions